# How to solve Python selenium webdriver returning blank files

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently in the process of systematically scraping data of an online retailer's website. I have been doing this once every week now for 2 months and my Python Code has been working great but when I tried to run it today, it returned blank files instead of my usual data. I tried multiple ways to solve this but haven't managed to fix it. I tried switching to geckodriver but same result. I also updated my selenium, chromedriver, chrome... but no luck. Has someone suggestions on fixing this?
(this is my first post so hopefully I displayed the code clearly)

```
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import re
        import csv
        from selenium import webdriver
        import numpy


        url = "https://www.zalando.be/sportsokken/_zwart/"

        driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path = "/Users/lisabyloos/Downloads/chromedriver")
        pages = numpy.arange(1,3,1)
        for page in pages:
          driver.get(url + "?p=" + str(page))
          html_content = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')

          soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

          product_divs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "_4qWUe8 w8MdNG cYylcv QylWsg SQGpu8 iOzucJ JT3_zV DvypSJ"})

          results = []

          for product in product_divs:
            results.append(product.get_text(separator=";"))

          import pandas as pd
          df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split(";") for sub in results])
          df.to_csv("myfile" + str(page) + ".csv" )
```

Comment: what is the reason you are also using bs4 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Classes of elements you try to find are dynamically generated and have changed.

**Note** *Pages change from time to time, but changes to structure are rarer than to styles. Therefore, it is always a good strategy to use elements or ids rather than classes for selection.*

### How to fix?

Adjust selecting criteria to get your results:

```
product_divs = soup.find_all('article')
```